# Android Lollipop behavior change

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, launchmode

As per changes in Android Lollipop, reference :

[StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27954026/lollipop-making-my-activity-stay-in-the-task-that-launched-the-share-intent)

[Cheese factory blog](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en)

I expect that when I start an activity of other application from my application, it should open in a new task even if the behavior is default (launchmode is standard). So, I made 2 test apps to verify the same behavior. But surpirisingly, the other app always opens up in my app's task, if there's no launchmode specified. I've tested this on Xiaomi Redmi Note 3 (5.1.1), Marshmallow emulator (x86), and the behavior is same for both. I'd appreciate some help on this, and also a link for reference from Android developer's site.

Some code :

```
Launching app : 
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
startActivity(intent);
break;

App to be launched : 
<activity android:name="com.android.sample.launchdemo.ActivityB">
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

On a button click from launching app, the intent is fired and activity B successfully opens up, but in the *same task*. Thanks in advance for any help/suggestions.

Comment: @Yvette You are correct, but unfortunately removing the launch mode doesn't change the behavior. I have updated the code snippet in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking through the documentation, the feeling I have is that standard mode works the same way as it did before Android 5.0 (Lollipop). The cheese factory blog post was the only one that specified that action and even in my own experience standard launch modes have opened an activity in the same task it was sent in (unless intent flags were passed through). Someone correct me if I am wrong but it is not specified in Android documentation that standard mode would open a new task. From the Android documentation:

> "standard" (the default mode): The system creates a new instance of the activity **in the task from which it was started** and routes the intent to it. The activity can be instantiated multiple times, each instance can belong to different tasks, and one task can have multiple instances. [See full documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

For what you are looking for, when firing off the `Intent`, the only way to guarantee a new task is use the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. You can set this by calling either `intent.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)` or `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)` (the latter is for chaining flags together because that method will return the intent).

After doing more research, the only change (relating to this) that appears to be made in Android 5.0 Lollipop is that the recent apps screen can show multiple instances of an activity.

> In previous releases, the recents screen could only display only one task for each app that the user interacted with most recently. Now your app can open more tasks as needed for additional concurrent activities for documents. This feature facilitates multitasking by letting users quickly switch between individual activities and documents from the recents screen, with a consistent switching experience across all apps. Examples of such concurrent tasks might include open tabs in a web browser app, documents in a productivity app, concurrent matches in a game, or chats in a messaging app.

To me this seems like the only change relating and the post (cheesefactory and SO) have `documentLaunchMode` set to create new tasks for each activity (which very well could be the case considering the cheesefactory had a "Gallery" app). Documentation on [concurrent documents](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html) and [documentLaunchMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#documentLaunchMode). `documentLaunchMode` and the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` can be configured to do similar things `documentLaunchMode` is preferred.

Comment: I have the same feeling too, but those 2 links are contradictory which is causing a little confusion. Also, as far as I remember I have seen this new behavior mentioned on developer's site somewhere, but couldn't find it again. It seems to have been lost somehow.

Comment: @gauravjain I have also found other instances of this behavior but never on a developer site, maybe the feature was implemented then removed? I will keep looking into this to see if I can find a solution

Comment: @gauravjain I have updated my answer to include more research and accept this answer as it is the closest one to a solution. Sorry for not finding a better one.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the documentation below.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/recents.html

=> when the user is using their browser, and they tap Share > Gmail. The Gmail app's Compose screen appears. Tapping the Recents button at that time reveals Chrome and Gmail running as separate tasks. In lower versions of Android, all of the activities appear as a single task, making the Back button the only means of navigation. Figure 2 shows how the Recents screen looks in Android 5.0 and higher, versus lower versions of the platform. The image on the left screen for Android 5.0 and higher, and the image on the right shows how it appears in lower versions of Android.

and refer to the following link.
[Lollipop: making my activity stay in the task that launched the share intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27954026/lollipop-making-my-activity-stay-in-the-task-that-launched-the-share-intent)

=> By default, launchMode of myfirstapp.MainActivity is "standard" and any intent flags weren't set.
 But after myfirstapp.MainActivity is started through share action of Album, the intent flag contains FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK, FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT.

When an activity is started through share, an activity which contains share in its Toolbar just sets Intent to its ShareActionProvider, and then ShareActionProvider starts an activity with this Intent - in this case, myfirstapp.MainActivity.

So I think that from Lollipop, the system begins a new task for the activity from a different app whose launchMode is "standard" only when the activity is started through share action.